# Video to image sequence

Tags: ios, image, animation, video, playback

Is it possible to extract images or convert a video to a sequence of images using the iPhone API? The goal is to play a video using some kind of animation, instead of the builtin video players. The reason for doing this is that I need to playback a video at reduced speed.

FFMpeg is not an option.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No, there is no public iPhone API available for that.

Your best option would actually be an open source alternative, like FFmpeg.

Comment: Hm, ye, after some research I've come to the same conclution. However, will FFMpeg be accepted to app store?

Comment: I dont see a reason why FFmpeg would be a reason to reject your app. However, the one thing you should be really concerned about is the fact that FFmpeg contains a lot of GPL code, which you cannot use in your closed source iPhone app unless you also make the source code of your own application available under the same license.

Comment: This is really old question but somehow it ends up in the search on top places. Let's have a look at AVAssetImageGenerator. So there is an API how that. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/media_reading_and_writing/creating_images_from_a_video_asset